# Добавление view в layout

Tags: android

Есть layout c параметрами

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams controlLayoutParam = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.BOTTOM);
```

рисует 3 картинки, я добавляю ещё 1 картинку, и она рисуется внизу слева, а хочется чтобы она была выше чем кнопки, и находилась над ними.

картинка добавляется в layout с такими параметрами:

`RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(337, 200);`

Вся работа производится в коде, без xml

Comment: а может приведете пример как нужно, например картинку :)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй после

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(337, 200);
```

написать

```
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
```